# Iterating over a reference to map

Tags: c++, reference, iterator

I have a function returning a reference to a map, something like this:

```
const std::map<T1, T2>& get_some_map(void) const
{
  ...
}

void main(void)
{
  const std::map<T1, T2>& some_map = get_some_map();
}
```

Now I want to iterate over this map, so I declare

```
      std::map<T1, T2>::iterator it     = some_map.begin();
const std::map<T1, T2>::iterator it_end = some_map.end();
```

but I get an error at the last two lines when I compile. Where am I wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type you need is `const_iterator`, not `iterator`.  Even better, just use `auto`.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate on the map you can do something like this:

```
for(auto&& pair : get_some_map()) {
    /// use the values in pair.first, pai.second... 
}
```

Comment: In the for loop is get_some_map() called at each iteration? In that case wouldn't it be better to use:
    const std::map<T1, T2>& some_map = get_some_map();
    for(auto&& pair : some_map) {
        /// use the values in pair.first, pai.second... 
    }
?

Comment: @Hybridslinky - nope: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: @Hybridslinky as pointed out already it's only called once, another important reason is that it keeps the map reference in the scope it's used.